# How can I set a google-font as default-font in CKEditor?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, google-font-api

I want to use 'Open Sans' as default-font in my CKEditor, but can't find out how.
I am using CKEditor `4.4.5 full`.

I've included the font in my html head:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then I tried to change CKEditor's default font by changing the CSS in its contents.css:

```
body
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I also tried to set it in my Javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_names = "Open Sans;";
CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = 'Open Sans';
```

But this only seems to influence the display of the 'Font' Toolbar, not the style by itself.

**note**: I can use 'Open Sans' when I am using the "ckeditor-gwf-plugin", but this doesn't help me to set it as default font either.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: did you try this one yet? found on the google fonts page. body{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;} right here: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Comment: @Stefan i don't know how this should change anything. this just adds "sans-serif" but doesn't help me to display "Open Sans".

Comment: You can do some thing like following -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339258/ckeditor-4-how-to-set-default-font

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama thanks, but i just found a solution that's much more simple. will post it as an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you need to style the content area of CKEditor? Than you need to create a css file and add it to your CKEditor config like this:

```
contentsCss : '/path/to/style.css',
```

And in the style.css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body, p { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
```

Make sure `/path/to/style.css` loads. Use your browsers developer tools.
Also set the appropriate selectors: `body`, `p` for text and maybe `h1, h2, h3`.

Most of the time the styling in this file will be the same typography styles used in your web application.

Comment: thank you! I haven't got the time to check if your solution is working as well. But I think my solution is much simpler, if you want a general default font for every instance of your CKEditor. plus your `some_selector` needs to be `body, p` in order to override the original style just as mentioned in my own answer.

Comment: ok, nevermind. I like your answer more than mine, since it allows to use custom css files. and I already tried it, it works for me. the two important things are: **1)** to use `@import` in your css file and **2)** to use `body, p` as your selector in order to make `font-size` work as well. would you mind adding the selector and some font-size to your answer?

Comment: `*` would maybe override the styles for select-options in the toolbar. only tested it with `body, p` so far, which works fine as it seems.

Comment: it's important to have `p` in the selector for setting the `font-size`

Answer (score 1):

***note:*** this is how you can **generally** change the default `font-family` and `font-size` for your CKEditor. In order to change it by using a custom CSS file, look at the accepted answer!

---

Just found out how to use a google font as default font in CKEditor:

```
/* contents.css of your CKEditor */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body
{
    /* Font */

    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

**note**: you need to add the google-font with `@import url`. and, be careful: `font-size` gets ignored here!

Then, with the help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545905/3391783,
I also managed to set the default `font-size`:

```
/* contents.css of your CKEditor */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body, p
{
    /* Font */

    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

**note**: you need to add the `p`-tag in addition to the `body`-tag. like the mentioned answer explains, the styles of the paragraphs are overwriting the `font-size` of your body.